# WebApi 2 - Json request pending

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

when I call one webapi from ajax, if I return something different from simple string or int, the request is still pending.

here my javascript:

```
var endPoint = "/api/services/attivita/set";
$.ajax({
    url: endPoint,
    data: JSON.stringify(
        {
        'id': attivita.IDTipoAttivita,
        'descrizione': $('#Descrizione').val()
        }
    ),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('ok');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('ko');
    }
});
```

and here webapi code

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/services/attivita/set")]
    public TipoAttivita SetAttivita([FromBody] dynamic obj)
    {
        var id = (int)obj.id;
        var descrizione = obj.descrizione.ToString();
        var nuovo = id == -1;

        var attivita = new TipoAttivita()
        //do stuff of attivita object
        this.CurrentDb.TipoAttivita.Add(attivita);
        this.CurrentDb.SaveChanges();

        return (attivita);
    }
```

If I change to "public int...." and "return(1);" at the end of the function everything works fine.

in WebApiConfig.cs I have this

```
var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
        {
            SerializerSettings = {ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore}
        };
        jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);
```

Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You want to set a break point inside SetAttivita action method, and debug it.

Comment: Can you show your TipoAttivita source code?

Comment: TipoAttivita is an object from entity framework generated model, and in debug mode the function go to the end but on the browser there's no response

Comment: [HttpGet] and [FromBody] for one controller action has no sense. You are breaking Http protocol

Comment: @KonstantinErshov not quite, the HTTP spec says GET requests are allowed to have a body, but it should have no semantic meaning to the request.  It makes no sense to send a body with GET, but it isn't breaking the protocol.

Comment: I've edited the code to get a post request from javascript and removed the httpget from the apicontroller, but is still pending

Answer (score 0):

Try to change return type to `IHttpActionResult` and return `Ok(attivita)`

Comment: with ihttpactionresult is still pending